# how do I print the ordering number for the i-th page in the `includepdf` command

Tags: xetex, page-numbering

I have a code like below. Now I want to print the *numerical order* of the page.
From 1 beginning in `R0.pdf` to last page ending in `R5.pdf`. This

```
 pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

Doesn't work. Perhaps I do not know where to place it.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}% MWE only

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{(\paperheight-2cm)/(\paperwidth-3cm)}% 1cm margin
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\delta}{\paperwidth-2cm-2*\scale*(\paperheight-3cm)-4mm}% 4mm fudge factor

\begin{document}

%  \includepdf[scale=1.02, nup=2x1,pages=1-8,trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{sh1.pdf}


  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R0.pdf}


  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R1.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R2.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R3.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R4.pdf}

  \includepdf[scale=\scale,noautoscale,nup=2x1,pages=1-,delta={\delta} 0pt,offset=0pt -3mm,% offset in reverse order
  trim=2.5cm 2.5cm 5.5cm 2.5cm]{R5.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand which number want to  use, and your example can not be compiled. Try to make an example using example-image-a4-numbered.pdf or example-image-ducks.pdf which are both in every current tex system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Suppose that I have 2 included pdfs with 4 and 3 pages resp. Now I want that the first pdf displays somewhere on the page (after compilation) the numbers 1,2,3 and 4, and the succeeding one 5,6 and 7. Just like an odrinary book. To your hint, this: http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-a4-numbered.pdf just gives some big numbers on colored background but no MWE in xetex. If you want to compile my code, you must use instead of `R0.pdf` any pdf in your working directory. Could you provide a MWE to number every page in my code ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually now I've found this: `https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-mwe/code/ci/default/tree/example-image-a4-numbered.tex` Where should I insert the `\dopage` command to do its work (to number each page)?